# How to stop pivot looping

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create a wizard control from the pivot control. To achieve this I need to stop the pivot looping. I want to stop the pivot control moving forward from the last item to the first and backwards from the first to the last.

I'm pretty sure I should be able to intercept the manipulations e.g. cancel if I detect a right to left manipulation on the last pivot item. I can capture this in ManipulationDelta but don't know how to cancel the manipulation.

I have tried setting e.Handled = True but it didn't work.

I tried to set IsHitTestVisisble to false but this kills all manipulations. I tried setting it back to true in ManipulationCompleted but this then allows all manipulations.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Are you targeting mango? You could use the Lockable Pivot in the Toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reply to your comment on Matts answer but I just wanted to point you to this:
http://forty3degrees.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/creating-a-swipable-contentcontrol/

It's the last entry in my very neglected blog and should provide a good base for creating a wizard using a pivot style swipe.

Calum.

EDIT: I tried to do what you wanted with the pivot but couldn't find a way to stop it looping. The only way that I can think of to achieve this would be to derive a custom control from Pivot. Unfortunately SelectedIndex/SelectedItem are not virtual so you would need to hide them (with the new modifier) and reproduce the logic from the base class.

Comment: Thanks Calum. I have marked this as the answer as you are the closest to suggesting a way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

The pivot is not designed to be used as a wizard and does not support stopping it's looping behaviour as this would create an inconsistent UX for users.

If you really must create a wizard do it with multiple pages.

Comment: I have created my own wizard control using horizontally positioned stack panels and transitions to move from one "page" to the next. It works very well. The only thing that lets it down is the swipe is not as "tactile" as the pivot ie it doesnt move with the swipe. Rather it requires a swipe to be completed before it moves. It struck me that I had basically reinvented the pivot and that I could re-use the pivot if I could stop it looping. I'm mostly there but just need help on the final bit.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a Pivot for a Wizard. Create your own transitions instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an alternative solution I've [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534190/2681948) - you can try to make use of XNA framework [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) and [Touch.FrameReported Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myPivot.IsHitTestVisible = false; // disable your Pivot
   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.HorizontalDrag; 
}

TouchPoint first;

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this);
    if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
        first = mainTouch;
    else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up && TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        if (mainTouch.Position.X < first.Position.X)
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex < myPivot.Items.Count - 1)
                myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        else if (mainTouch.Position.X > first.Position.X)
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex > 0)
                myPivot.SelectedIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```

Thought it would probably work from WP7.1 as TouchPanel is available from that version of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to keep the Pivot from looping, here is a quick and dirty hack:

```
 int previousSelectedIndex = 0;

    public PageWithPivot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pivot.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(pivot_SelectionChanged); 
    }


    private void pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (pivot.SelectedIndex == 0 && previousSelectedIndex == <number Of screens - 1>)
            pivot.SelectedIndex = <number Of screens - 1>;
        previousSelectedIndex = pivot.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

This causes your PivotControl to jump back to the last pivotItem. Not very pretty but works.

Comment: stackoverflow ;) exception and number of screens is pivot1.Items.Count

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird because it only works in the Emulator. I guess you shan't mess with the UI

You can use MVVM:

```
<phone:Pivot Foreground="Black"
                 Name="pivot1"
                 Title="AIDE"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Cs:

```
    private class HelpViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public HelpViewModel()
        {

        }

        private int _SelectedItem = 0;
        public int SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedItem != value)
                {
                    if (value == 3)
                        _SelectedItem = 0;
                    else
                        _SelectedItem = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public AppHelpPivot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = new HelpViewModel();
    }
```