# Prevent scrolling on last item of panorama item or pivot item wp7 c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have n number of pivot items . How to stop scrolling from last to first item. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop pivot looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669546/how-to-stop-pivot-looping) - in short: **impossible**.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Indeed there is no 'simple' way to do that. But I can imagine a locked Pivot, where you handle changing items programatically by other events (Touch) - there you can put any logic.

Comment: @Romasz Yes, locked pivot would work. But OP uses WP7.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov You may be right - it depends on OS version. I don't have WP7 emulator right now, but according to MSDN at least WP7.1 should handle that task (I assume that there is an ability to lock Pivot - IsHitTestVisivle).

Comment: [logical Code here][1]

please  check  this..hope  it  will  work..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28184642/3770310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that would work, hence as Ulugbek Umirov said in comments - it is dependant on OS version. I don't have emulator right now to try, but you may try to do it like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myPivot.IsHitTestVisible = false; // disable your Pivot
   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.HorizontalDrag; 
}

TouchPoint first;
private const int detectRightGesture = 20;

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this);
    if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
        first = mainTouch;
    else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up && TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X < -detectRightGesture)
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex < myPivot.Items.Count - 1)
                myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        else if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X > detectRightGesture)
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex > 0)
                myPivot.SelectedIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```

According to [MSDN - TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) should be available from WP7.1 and [Touch.FrameReported Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) should be available on WP7.0. Therefore there is a chance that it will work.

You have to add reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch` assembly.

I've also added `detectRightGesture` so that Pivot won't be switched on small vertical drags, it's a matter of test if that will be needed.

Comment: I'm testing your code. Just one question, what is `myMap`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Heh - an artifact from my old code ;) And thanks for testing it.

Comment: It works on WP7.1. But I changed your code a bit to suit OP needs.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks for information and edit, now I also remember why I had that comparison to 0 - in some cases it may be needed to disable switching with small vertical drags - drag has always some vertical and horizontal coordinates.