# Disabling swipe gesture in Windows Phone 8.1 pivot control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am making a Universal app. For the windows phone part I have implemented a pivot page in it. Now I want the swipe gesture (for navigating through different pivot items) in pivot page to be disabled so that only when a button on the first PivotItem is tapped then it shows the second PivotItem. I tried setting the IsHitTestVisible property of the Pivot control to false but then all the PivotItem are blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes against the **WINDOWS UI Guide** and shouldn't really be implemented.

However, for the sake of theory if nothing else, you could do something like this.

Consider you have 5 pivot items, give your first and last PivotItem a name as

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Item1" Name="first">
...

 <controls:PivotItem Header="Item5" Name="last">
```

Handle the Pivot's `LoadingPivotItem` and `LoadedPivotItem` events. You can then do something like this:

```
//class level variable we use for the current pivot
PivotItem currentItem = null;

private void Pivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
//if the next item is going to be "first" pivot
//and the previous item was the "last" pivot...
if (e.Item == first && currentItem == last)
{
  //...reset the Pivot back to the last one.
   mainPivot.SelectedItem = last;
}

//same theory as above but checking if we're 
//sliding to the last one from the first one
if (e.Item == last && currentItem == first)
{
   mainPivot.SelectedItem = first;
}
}

private void mainPivot_LoadedPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
 //once the pivot is loaded, update the currentItem
 currentItem = e.Item;
}
```

Hope this works..
For any queries .. revert back.